# Conversion of .class to .dex

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I have 1 java program which is using Android Keystore APIs. 
We need to run this prog to validate some sign operations on android based board.

Running this program through android studio works fine i.e. creating a sample application and install that apk. 
But we need to run this program through command line, as the actual program wont be in apk format.

When trying to convert this program to dex format it is throwing error.

Compilation is succefull by passing android.jar as classpath

```
javac -cp /<path>/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar  ApiClientAndroidKeyStore.java
```

But dex conversion is failing with below error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:752)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:718)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1200(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$FileBytesConsumer.processFileBytes(Main.java:1645)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:672)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:574)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Caused by: com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.parseClass(Main.java:764)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$1500(Main.java:85)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$ClassParserTask.call(Main.java:1684)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:749)
```

On further debugging observed that android.jar only contains API defns but actual source code is not present.

1) Is there any android.jar available which contains source code too(size might be an issue)

2) Can we pass source code at dex conversion step

3) Does apk contains source code also while building or reference is enough

4) Can we use same commands from command line which android studio uses while building apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)`. Version 0x34 (52 decimal) is a java 8 class file, which older versions of dx are not able to handle.

There are 2 ways you can solve this. The first is to run the android sdk manager and grab the latest version of the build tools. This should contain a newer version of the dx tool, which can handle java 8 class files.

The other solution is to tell javac to compile for an earlier version of java, with the -source and -target flags. e.g.

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -cp /<path>/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar  ApiClientAndroidKeyStore.java
```

Regarding the android.jar file only containing stubs - this is normal and nothing to worry about. javac only needs the stubs for compiling. Those classes are provided by the Android framework and aren't included in your application. So javac doesn't actually need class files with the full implementations of those classes - it only needs to know the class/method/field signatures so it can properly link against them.

Comment: Using latest build-tools solve the issue, thanks for reply.
Can you also check this que - any help will be great - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428427/android-no-such-provider-exception-for-androidkeystore-in-cli