# AndroidKeyStore implementation not found while running through cli

Tags: java, android, security, android-studio, android-keystore

I have 1 java program which is using Android Keystore APIs. We are running this prog(as Java prog but not android application) to use crypto operations on android based board.

Running this program through android studio works fine i.e. creating a sample application(which internally uses keystore APIs via AndroidKeystore securitye Provider) and install that apk. But we need to run this program through command line, as the actual program wont be in apk format.

Looks like Security Provider AndroidKeyStore is working only while running with an app, but not via command line.

Tried following ways :

1) Compiled prog via javac, created jar and then converted into dex to run through cli

2) created jar from android studio and then converted into dex to run through cli

3) Android application is working on both emulator and board,

```
126|u0_a82@msm8916_64:/data/data/berserker.android.apps.sshdroid/home $ dalvikvm -cp apiclient.dex com.example.test_jar.ApiClientAndr>
in api client main
java.security.KeyStoreException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore AndroidKeyStore implementation not found
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:119)
    at com.example.test_jar.ApiClientAndroidKeyStore.main(ApiClientAndroidKeyStore.java:279)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: KeyStore AndroidKeyStore implementation not found
    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.notFound(Engine.java:190)
    at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:139)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:116)
    ... 1 more
```

Following are the list of Security Providers

1) When running in emulator/board

```
Name: AndroidKeyStoreBCWorkaround, Information:Android KeyStore security provider to work around Bouncy Castle
Name: AndroidOpenSSL, Information: Android's OpenSSL-backed security provider
Name: BC, Information: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.52
Name: Crypto, Information: HARMONY (SHA1 digest; SecureRandom; SHA1withDSA signature)
Name: HarmonyJSSE, Information: Harmony JSSE Provider
Name: AndroidKeyStore, Information:Android KeyStore security provider
```

2) When running via cli

```
Name: AndroidOpenSSL, Information: Android's OpenSSL-backed security provider
Name: BC, Information: BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.52
Name: Crypto, Information: HARMONY (SHA1 digest; SecureRandom; SHA1withDSA signature)
Name: HarmonyJSSE, Information: Harmony JSSE Provider
```

Comment: m., it seems similar to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647990/why-command-line-dalvikvm-uses-standard-java-security-libraries-keystore-inste). Did you find any information?